# C# Process + Backgroundworker & timer error

Tags: c#

I have some code that spawns a process, the file being executed is a Java application and my intent is to read the output from it.

The problem is that when I call `Start`, I am unable to read the output stream after that point. If I test and call `Console.Beep` after calling `Start` then the beep will occur - so it is obviously executing these lines.

```
Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false; 

Process java = new Process();
java.StartInfo.FileName = "java";
java.StartInfo.Arguments = "-Xms1024M -Xmx1024M -jar craftbukkit-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar nogui";
java.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
java.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
java.Start();

System.Console.Beep();
System.Console.Write("hejsan");
StreamReader Reader = java.StandardOutput;

txtLog.Text = Convert.ToString(System.Console.Read());
broadcast(Convert.ToString(System.Console.Read()), "[Server]", false);
```

Why can't I read from the output stream?

Comment: Please define the problem, as it stands this is a poorly formulated question.

Comment: I say again, After java.Start() it wont return System.Console.ReadLine(), Read(), or anythign!

Comment: You need to wait for the process to end before reading the stream.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this Microsoft reference of [StandardOutput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput.aspx).

Basically, you need to call `WaitForExit` and attempt to read the stream *after* that. It's a blocking call, so unless you do some funky stuff with it and asynchronism, this is fairly straight forward:

```
if (java.Start())
{
    java.WaitForExit();
    var reader = java.StandardOutput;
    output = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

It's worth mentioning here that the `Start` method returns a boolean value indicating whether or not the process was actually started - this helps us decide what to do, and whether or not we can do it.

On another note, I can't help but notice that you don't actually *try* to read from the output stream, you simply declare a variable with a reference to it; in order to utilise it, then you will need to call the methods exposed by the class, such as `ReadToEnd` - I have added usage to the example above.